# NVidia 460 update disables HDMI audio output

Tags: sound, hdmi

After I updated the NVidia driver to 460, the HDMI audio disappeared.

The video card is Quadro M1200 Mobile
Thinkpad P51
Ubuntu 20.10 64bit

Any idea on how to recover the audio output?

Answer (score 0):

Does the solution here work for you?  https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/no-hdmi-audio-on-nvidia-1660-super-driver-460-ubuntu-20-10/165785/5

Unfortunately, I'm on Linux Mint 20.1 and can't reproduce the fix.  Only option I've found is to revert to 450.

EDIT: I solved this with the kernel parameter "pcie_port_pm=off".  Ubuntu 20.04 and related users should give this a shot.